# PXF Certificate will not install -dump command completed successfully

Tags: batch-file, cmd, certificate

I am trying to install a `.pfx` [certificate](/questions/tagged/certificate) through a login script, I have one that already installs, but is about to expire. I have changed the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to point to the new `.pxf`, *(which has the same name)*, and entered the new password. However it does not install.

I have run this on my machine locally pointing to the cert on my desktop, with the correct password and it says when complete,

```
certutil -f -p "PA$$WORD" -importpfx "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\desktop\CERTIFICATE.pfx" NoRoot

CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

prior to this info, It seems to be returning info RE: our domain CA

The Original code is:

```
certutil -f -p "PA$$WORD" -importpfx "%LOGONSERVER%\SYSVOL\Certs\CERTIFICATE.pfx" NoRoot
```

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? Certutil is different of e.g. 8 and 10...

Comment: A variety of windows 7, 10 and servers 2008R2 and 2016. However as noted before the previous cert was deploying on all platforms. I have noted that the new cert when trying to export from a store it won't allow me to export the key, unlike the first one. So I believe that it is the way the cert was produced that is stopping the install. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Latest Win10 returns `CertUtil: -importPFX command completed successfully.` for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my original comment, i have been using the command to install the pfx and worked for years. I now have a new PFX and I assume that it has been created differently not allowing the export of the password, when exporting from store. I believe that its an issue with the pfx not the commands.